# Is there a way to see questions with answers of a specified score under a tag?

Tags: discussion, filtering

I know it's very specific, but worth a shot... I would like to see answers in a tag that have 8-30 score. I want to learn from good answers to improve my own answers. The upper limit is there because in my experience, answers with 30+ will get more votes just because they are on top and already have many votes.

Comment: Your title says "questions" yet your body text says "answers". Which is it?

Comment: My title says "questions with answers" and that's what I mean.

Comment: Ah - I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something similar to [[c#] votes:8 is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A8), which returns a list of answers with at least 8 votes for questions tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). As I can see, the number after "votes:" seems to be interpreted as number of up-votes.

There isn't a way to put a limit on the number of votes using the search tools; you can just set the minimum number of votes.  However, you can get this manually by [sorting with the 'votes' tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20is%3aanswer%20votes%3a8) and browsing to the [33rd page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=33&tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20is%3aanswer%20votes%3a8) (get there faster by changing `?page=33` in the URL).